Mi aplicación no lanza una segunda activity
Estoy creando una aplicación que genera un número aleatorio entre 1 y 50, pida que el usuario lo adivine e informe si ganó o si el número es mayor o menor al ingresado. Cuando acierte, quiero lanzar una segunda activity que informe que ha acertado pero en el intent la aplicación se cierra. Es decir, la aplicación funciona correctamente hasta que el usuario acierta el número, momento en el que la aplicación se cierra. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias.
MainActivity.kt:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var tv2: TextView
    private lateinit var tv3: TextView
    private lateinit var et1 : EditText
    private lateinit var boton1: Button
    private var numero: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2)
        tv3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3)
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1)
        boton1 = findViewById(R.id.boton1)

        val preferencias = getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val v = preferencias.getInt("puntos", 0).toString()
        tv2.setText(v)
        numero = 1 + (Math.random() * 50).toInt()

        val tg = ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME)

        boton1.setOnClickListener {
            val valor = et1.text.toString().toInt()
            if (numero == valor) {

                actualizapuntos()

                val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

            } else {
                tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD)
                if (valor > numero)
                    tv3.text = "Ingresó un número mayor al que penso la maquina."
                else
                    tv3.text = "Ingresó un número menor al que penso la maquina."
            }
        }

    }

    private fun actualizapuntos() {
       ...
    }
}

ResultActivity.kt
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var btnVolver: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnVolver)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        btnVolver.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PRUEBA"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Todos los componentes necesarios están creados en sus correspondientes layouts.
Logcat:

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 21821
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prueba/com.example.prueba.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3950)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:99)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2616)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:222)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:314)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8716)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:565)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:217)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:1010)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:898)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:865)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:667)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
at com.example.prueba.ResultActivity.(ResultActivity.kt:13)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1389)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3934)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:99) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2616) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:222) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:314) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8716) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:565) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)


Conecta tu dispositivo al pc, ejecuta el flujo hasta que se cierre y lee lo que pone en la consola de logcat donde te estará poniendo la traza exacta de error, usas el enlace [edit] y la añades a la pregunta. Somos programadores, no adivinos! Si no vemos el error exacto cómo crees que podemos saber qué pasa?? Cualquier excepción no controlada puede hacer que se cierre tu aplicación, no es posible debugar estas cosas sin ... bueno, sin realmente debugar estas cosas!

Disculpa. Olvidé el logcat. Gracias por responder.

En base a las respuestas a esta pregunta, tu problema parece estar en esta en esta línea:
var btnVolver: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnVolver)

Porque no puedes usar findViewById antes de que la actividad sea creada.
El mejor momento para obtener referencias a tus vistas en la función onCreate, después de llamar setContentView; sino la actividad estaría vacía y la vista no sería encontrada.

¡Muchas gracias!
